# Debugging python script executed in chroot environment

Tags: python, linux, eclipse, pydev, chroot

Is there a way to debug python script which is executed inside chroot by eclipse which is installed on my machine and chroot doesn't see it? I am not allowed to install eclipse inside chroot.

Answer (score 0):

You could always use the python debugger. [Docs for PDB](http://docs.python.org/library/pdb.html) This allows you to create breakpoints in your programs. Poke variables and also generally have a look at the internals.